# pinax setup_project command doesnt work

Tags: pinax

when i try to create new project in pinax, this is what i get

(mysite-env) (path)>pinax-admin setup_project mysite2
Unknown command: 'setup_project'
Type pinax-admin-script.py help for usage.

pinax-admin clone_project is working well. help please

Answer (score 0):

You could start cloning an existing sample project.

This would install the "skeleton" for a pinax project. Then you can add or remove apps.

```
>> pinax-admin clone_project basic_project mysite
```

For a lists of sample projects

```
>> pinax-admin clone_project -l
```